# Defining parameters so that they obey multiple constraints

Tags: modeling, parameterization, stan, constraint

I'd like to define parameters $\beta_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,I$ for a problem so that they automatically obey some constraints. The constraints are:

1. $\sum_{i=1,\ldots,I} w_i \beta_i = c_1$ and
2. $\sum_{i=1,\ldots,I} w_i \beta_i^2 < c_1^2 + c_2$,

where $c_2>0$, $w_i>0$ and $\sum_{i=1,\ldots,I} w_i = 1$.

I know how I would achieve the first constraint, if this were the only one:

- I would define $\beta_{\text{raw }i} \in [-\infty, \infty]$ for $i=1,\ldots,I-1$.
- Then, I would define $\beta_i := c_1 + \beta_{\text{raw }i} / w_i$ for $i<I$ and $\beta_I := c_1 - \sum_{i=1,\ldots,I-1} \beta_{\text{raw }i} / w_I$.

This is basically a shifted version of how one typically enforces a sum-to-zero constraint. By doing that, we can immediately see that
$$\sum_{i=1,\ldots,I} w_i \beta_i  = \left( \sum_{i=1,\ldots,I-1} w_i (c_1 + \beta_{\text{raw }i} / w_i) \right) +  w_I \left( c_1 - \sum_{i=1,\ldots,I-1} \beta_{\text{raw }i} / w_I   \right) \\  = \left( \sum_{i=1,\ldots,I} w_i c_i \right) + \sum_{i=1,\ldots,I-1} w_i \beta_{\text{raw }i} / w_i - \sum_{i=1,\ldots,I-1} \beta_{\text{raw }i} = 1.$$

However, I fail to see how to add the second additional constraint (esp. given its quadratic nature, a second linear constraint would have been easier). Any ideas/suggestions?

In case context matters: I'm trying to define a model in Stan that obeys these constraints, because otherwise the inference does not capture what I know of the real world situation (first constraint) and a covariance matrix becomes invalid (second constraint).

Comment: Usually what we know about the "real world" is uncertain, so have you considered incorporating these relationships as prior distributions rather than constraints?  If you really need hard constraints, then the algebra looks simple enough: solve the quadratic equation for $\beta_I$ and $\beta_{I-1}$ in terms of $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_{I-2},c_1,c_2.$ Because there may be two or zero solutions it will be a little messy but it's straightforward.

Comment: I've got a situation where a we observe a mixture distribution (and we know the mixture weights). We know the the realized mean of the mixture is by definition the weighted sum of the realized means of the components. Additionally, you have a constraint implied by width of the observed distribution (the realized means of the mixture components simply cannot lie beyond the observed mixture distribution).

Comment: I suspect you might not be approaching the formulation of your model correctly, but the description is too vague to suggest what to do.  It would help for your post to describe your data and your statistical objectives instead of posing an abstract mathematical question whose solution might be inappropriate or even wrong in your application.